# BIRT Date Parameters for Informix Queries

Tags: birt, informix

I'm running into a wall of syntax errors trying to use a Date parameter in a query against an Informix  (11.50) database. I'm using this query:

```
select
    distinct SOMEVARIABLE
from
    SOMETABLE
where SOMEDATETIME > datetime (?) year to minute
and SOMEDATETIME < datetime (2014-10-30) year to day
```

The query parameter type is set to Date and the report paramter is set to DateTime, formatted as a Short Date.

The error I get is: java.sql.SQLException: Non-numeric character in datetime or interval.

If I comment out the where clause, I can get BIRT to show me the value it's interpolating in the error: **2014-10-27 00:00**.

As far as I can tell, this is the proper formatting for an Informix datetime literal. I'm beginning to lose what's left of my mind here...

**Edit:**

It looks like this may be a combination of my inexperience with Informix and my environment. I'm formulating and testing my queries with SQuirrel, using the same JDBC config as BIRT. In SQuirrel, I'm getting syntax errors if I don't use the long datetime literal format *datetime (YYYY-MM-DD) year to day*.

Michał's answer pointed me in the right direction. Cutting the literal down to just *YYYY-MM-DD* in the query within BIRT worked just fine.

I'm guessing this has something to do with how SQuirrel is setting up it's session with the database, but sufficient to the report is the evil thereof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use prepared statement parameters and cast it to datetime.

My quick Jython scrips shows that with `datetime` (YEAR TO SECOND) you can use something like:

```
pstm = db.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM _d_test WHERE dt>?")
pstm.setString(1, "2010-01-01 00:00:00")
```

And with `date` (YEAR TO DAY) you can use something like:

```
pstm = db.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM _d_test WHERE d>?")
pstm.setString(1, "2010-01-01")
```